# Cobol XML- Suppress Option

Tags: xml, cobol

I'm using the below code to generate XML statements.

```
01 GrpHdr.
      02 A1.
      03 MsgId                         PIC X(50) VALUE SPACES.
      03 Test3.
        05 Test31.
          07 Test32                    PIC X(10) VALUE SPACES.
        05 Test4.
          07 Test5.
            09 Test6.
              11 Test7                 PIC X(10) VALUE SPACES.
    MAIN-PARA.
    
            MOVE 'MESSAGE ID'          TO MsgId.
            MOVE 'TEST32'                TO Test32.
            MOVE SPACES               TO Test7.
    
            INITIALIZE OUTPUT-XML.
    
                XML GENERATE OUTPUT-XML from Grphdr
SUPPRESS Test31 EVERY NONUMERIC ELEMENT WHEN SPACES
                  ON EXCEPTION
                     DISPLAY 'GENERATE XML Error-Header'
                  NOT ON EXCEPTION
                     CONTINUE
            END-XML
            
DISPLAY 'OUTPUT:' OUTPUT-XML .

    MAIN-EXIT.
        EXIT.
```

I have populated proper values (non empty) to MsgId and Test32 tags and populated SPACES to Test7 tag.I was expecting output like below,

```
<GrpHdr>
<A1>
    <MsgId>MESSAGE ID</MsgId>
    <Test3>
        <TEST31>
            <TEST32>TEST32</TEST32>
        </TEST31>
    </Test3>
</A1>
</GrpHdr>
```

But im getting the output like below and its skipping all the tags after MsgID and not display TEST32 tags.

```
<GrpHdr>
<A1>
    <MsgId>MESSAGE ID</MsgId>
</A1>
</GrpHdr>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        XML GENERATE OUTPUT-XML from Grphdr
         SUPPRESS EVERY NONUMERIC ELEMENT WHEN SPACES
          ON EXCEPTION
             DISPLAY 'GENERATE XML Error-Header'
          NOT ON EXCEPTION
             CONTINUE
    END-XML
```

The above syntax works for me. No need to mention the variable name in SUPPRESS.

Comment: Looks like Q+A - welcome! I suggest to accept your own answer as "works for me" - well done.